# EntitySet<T> in LINQ to SQL- using it and removing it

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-sql, asp.net-4.0

I've got a pair of tables in my database. One of which has a primary key (a simple numerical ID), the other has that ID as a foreign key.

The first table has suddenly gained an `EntitySet<OtherTable>`. If I add a new `OtherTable()` to this, is it automatically sent to the database, and the ID's linked up, etc, when I use `SubmitChanges()`?

Secondly, the relationship isn't many-to-one, it's one-to-one, a corresponding entry in the second table is optional and singular. As such, a container like `EntitySet` isn't really appropriate for this relationship. An `OtherTable?` would be a more appropriate representation. How can I inform LINQ to SQL of this?

Answer (score 1):

Set Unique = true in the associaton properties. That should adjust it to being 1:1

Comment: This wasn't exactly it, but it did cause me to look in the right place- one of the other association properties is many-to-one or one-to-one.